# How to show thumbnail selected file of custom option?

Tags: custom-options, thumbnail, magento1.9.2.4

Could you advise How to show thumbnail selected file of custom option?

[image]

Comment: Can you please tell, where you want image option - In frontend or admin

Comment: Front-end when customer uploaded an image before Add to Cart.

Answer (score 0):

For this, any specific option is not given in magento,

You have to select data (either Image name or url) that you saved in database after uploading and display here simply with  tag, that means you have to code for this.

Magento don't give any feature like this.

Comment: I have tested this code but not work when added the js files

Comment: Simply retrive image url or name from database, and show it on the page where you want. Dont go for the above code.

Comment: How can I change the image from src="" to src="[retrived url]" after selection?  http://109.199.122.11/~cliffp99/childsown/index.php/product/softie-create-small.html

Comment: Yor are giving wrong path, please give exact url so that image can be visible.

Comment: After saving Image will be saved in folder like media  or skin folder, search where your image saved, and give that path.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this code but every javascript is not work when added the src.(http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js)

[showimage.html](http://www.filedropper.com/showimage)